# How to insert jsdoc @param programmatically in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

Is there a way to paste jsdoc descriptions programmatically? I mean I have some similar functions, but with slightly different arguments. Depending on the function I would like to have a different doc description. I can not find help in the jsdoc documentation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. The point of jsdoc is that it is in the source code so that documentation can be derived directly from the source. Only you can put the documentation in the source, because you know what your functions do. For each of your functions, insert the necessary jsdoc block to describe it. Some code editors such as VSCode provide some help by automatically inserting the @param lines for you, but you still have to provide all the descriptions.

Comment: @JohnRC What i'm trying to achieve is like a pre-compiler, inserting this piece of jsdoc text depending on the context or the function. Is it really like you have to statically write it for each function?

Comment: I don't know of a utility that will add `@param` lines after the code has been written but maybe someone else has. I have always used VSCode, which has plugins for js than automatically generate the `@param` lines when you start the jsdoc comment for a function. You may find the code editor that you use has a similar facility.